# Changing primary key data type in Production DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF code-first. I need to change the datatype of primary key of one table in our production database.

```
public class Course 
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id {get; set;}    //This needs to be changed to int

   public string Name {get;set;}

   public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups {get;set;}
}

public class Group
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id {get; set;}

   public string Name {get;set;}

   public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses{get;set;}
}
```

As the above is a Many-Many relationship, EF has created a join table `GroupCourses` automatically with  PK & FK  as both  `Group_Id` and `Course_Id`. Which is fine until now.

Now I need to change the primary key in `Course` entity to `int` from `Guid`.

I changed the datatype from `Guid` to `int` and successfully created a new migration. But when I try to run the command `update-database`, I am getting below error.

> Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int in query

I am not sure how to fix the above error.

Also, I think it's impossible to change the datatype of a primary key field without losing data (of course, we can copy from backup manually). I hope I am wrong.

Can someone please tell me is there any better way of achieving this without losing data ?

**NOTE** : I have gone through other SO posts related and other internet forums but no luck.

Comment: Could you do a migration to add a CourseTemp which upserts all the data from your old Course table to the Temp with the `Seed()` method? Then you could do another migration to delete the Original course and rename the CoureseTemp class/table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the type clash error because the generated migration tries to do directly `ALTER COLUMN` on the affected columns to change the type from `Guid` to `integer`, and it is not possible because the `Guid` values can not be implicitly converted to `integer` values.

You have to manually modify your migration. Remove the `AlterColumn` lines. In order to migrate your existing course ids without data loss you can temporarily rename the existing `Guid` columns (adding a suffix `_Old`), create new columns with the right new name and type, fill the contents in the relationship table with the right values using an `UPDATE` with a `SELECT`, and finally delete the old columns:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.GroupCourses", "Course_Id", "dbo.Courses");
    DropIndex("dbo.GroupCourses", new[] { "Course_Id" });
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Courses");
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.GroupCourses");

    //Removed: AlterColumn("dbo.Courses", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
    RenameColumn("dbo.Courses", "Id", "Id_Old"); //Added
    AddColumn("dbo.Courses", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true)); //Added

    //Removed: AlterColumn("dbo.GroupCourses", "Course_Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    RenameColumn("dbo.GroupCourses", "Course_Id", "Course_Id_Old"); //Added
    AddColumn("dbo.GroupCourses", "Course_Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false)); //Added
    Sql(@"UPDATE gc SET gc.Course_Id = c.Id " 
            + "FROM dbo.GroupCourses as gc " 
            + "INNER JOIN dbo.Courses as c ON gc.Course_Id_Old = c.id_Old"); //Added

    DropColumn("dbo.GroupCourses", "Course_Id_Old"); //Added
    DropColumn("dbo.Courses", "Id_Old");    //Added

    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Courses", "Id");
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.GroupCourses", new[] { "Group_Id", "Course_Id" });
    CreateIndex("dbo.GroupCourses", "Course_Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.GroupCourses", "Course_Id", "dbo.Courses", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
}
```

I marked in the code the lines I changed with the comments `//Added` and `//Removed`. The rest of the code is the original one in the migration as generated with `Add-Migration` after changing the property type to `int` in the model.

You only have to fill with an `UPDATE` the values in the column in the relationship table. The values in `Courses.Id` column will be auto-generated, as it is an `identity` column.

You should also figure out the `Down()` method and implement the reverse process, or leave it as it is if you really are never going to downgrade your database to a previous migration.

You can also do this by splitting the code between the migration and the seeder. It would be more correct conceptually, as you are supposed to use the migrations for schema modifications and the seeder for data modifications. But I think it is easier this way, and you need only one migration, while with the seeder approach you would need two migrations: one with all the code included above except the `UPDATE` and the sentences that drop the `_Old` columns, and another one just with the dropping of the `_Old` columns. The `UPDATE` part would be implemented in the seeder.

A warning: the SQL code included in the `UPDATE` sentence works with `Sql Server` but might not work with other database engines. It is another downside of using the migration instead of the seeder.

Comment: Very detailed answer. Thanks :-)