# Change data type from int to long of key property in model .net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core-2.2

I want to change the data type of the primary key of a model in ASP.Net core 2.2 from int to long since it is about to run out of the int range. The application was done code-first and uses SQL server as database.

Changing the data type in the model works and running Add-Migration works too, but Update-Database fails with the error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The index 'IX_tblMTransactions_OriginalTransactionId' is dependent on column 'OriginalTransactionId'.
The object 'FK_tblMTransactions_tblMTransactions_OriginalTransactionId' is dependent on column 'OriginalTransactionId'.
```

So I read about it and it seems that there are some adjustments that need to be done to the migration like dropping foreign keys and indexes prior to the column change and bringing them back afterwards. Unfortunately I couldn't find any helpful information about doing this in .net core 2.2, the closest one I found was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512778/changing-primary-key-data-type-in-production-db) but it talks about .net core 2.1 and the option `DropForeignKey` and `DropIndex`
mentioned there don't seem to be available any longer on .net core 2.2 according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.dropforeignkey?view=efcore-2.1).

Here is the migration class:

```
public partial class _20190817_1746 : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
            name: "OriginalTransactionId",
            table: "tblMTransactions",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(int),
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
            name: "Id",
            table: "tblMTransactions",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(int))
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)
            .OldAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "OriginalTransactionId",
            table: "tblMTransactions",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(long),
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "Id",
            table: "tblMTransactions",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(long))
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)
            .OldAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the columns, keys and indexes of that table:
[image: Table]

Does anybody know how to adjust the migration class in .NET Core 2.2 in order to make that work?

Thanks

Comment: `DropForeignKey` / `DropIndex` are available in 2.2. Just the link (documentation) is for 2.1, and there is no documentation for 2.2

Comment: Interesting - but is it in a different namespace than the one mentioned in the article? Because it doesn't find it under `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations` and Ctrl. Dot (Visual Studio) doesn't find it under a different namespace either.

Comment: Sorry, the linked question is for EF6. For EF Core all these are instance methods of the `MigrationBuilder` class (like `CreateTable` or `AlterColumn` from the generated migration etc.). Just look at `migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "...", table: "...")` etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev, it actually worked as you said - see answer below. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) I was able to find the solution. I had to add the dropping and Creating of the indexes and keys manually like this:

```
public partial class _20190817_2317 : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_tblMTransactions_tblMTransactions_OriginalTransactionId",
            table: "tblMTransactions");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_tblMTransactions_OriginalTransactionId",
            table: "tblMTransactions");

        migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_tblMTransactions",
            table: "tblMTransactions");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
            name: "OriginalTransactionId",
            table: "tblMTransactions",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(int),
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
            name: "Id",
            table: "tblMTransactions",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(int))
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)
            .OldAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

        migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_tblMTransactions",
            table: "tblMTransactions",
            column: "Id");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_tblMTransactions_OriginalTransactionId",
            table: "tblMTransactions",
            column: "OriginalTransactionId");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_tblMTransactions_tblMTransactions_OriginalTransactionId",
            table: "tblMTransactions",
            column: "OriginalTransactionId",
            principalTable: "tblMTransactions",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "OriginalTransactionId",
            table: "tblMTransactions",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(long),
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "Id",
            table: "tblMTransactions",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(long))
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)
            .OldAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
    }
}
```

Thanks again, Ivan!!

Comment: Don't you have to do the same for the Down method? First drop the keys and indexes, the do the alter and then add the keys and indexes again?

Comment: If you have a lot of records in the table it can take a long time to add the primary key. I had to extent the command timeout: Database.SetCommandTimeout(150000); see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006847/how-to-set-entity-framework-core-migration-timeout

Comment: Yes, in a perfect world you should take care of it in the `Down()` methode as well, just that at the project I am working on, we never undo a migration after it is in production, this is why we are not required to modify it.

Comment: For me the migration was not enough, I had to change the column type also in the dbContext (entity.Property(...).HasColumnType(-NEW TYPE-)).